# Fresco: Use current image displayed in Drawee as a placeholder for next request

Tags: android, facebook, fresco

I play multiple images sequentially on the same `SimpleDraweeView`, the issue is that when submitting a new imageURI request, the`SimpleDrweeView` will remove the current displayed image and replace it with nothing until the URI is downloaded. So it will leave gaps in the playing sequence ( you could think of what I'm trying to do is cartoon animation using local photos). What I would like for the SimpleDrweeView to leave the current image as is until the new one is downloaded and then just swap it when it's ready.

I tried using the low-res/high-res scheme from [this](https://github.com/facebook/fresco/issues/236) ticket to put the old uri as a placeholder but that didn't work (had the same effect as before).

This is what I have now:

```
 SimpleDraweeView draweeView = (SimpleDraweeView) findViewById(R.id.my_image_view);

 draweeView.setImageURI(uri /* local image */);
```

And this is what I tried so far (didn't work):

```
                SimpleDraweeView draweeView = (SimpleDraweeView) findViewById(R.id.my_image_view);

            Uri lowResUri, highResUri;
            DraweeController controller = Fresco.newDraweeControllerBuilder().setTapToRetryEnabled(true)
                    .setLowResImageRequest(ImageRequest.fromUri((Uri) draweeView.getTag())) /*naive way to test the low/high res feature*/
                    .setImageRequest(ImageRequest.fromUri(uri))
                    .setOldController(draweeView.getController())
                    .build();
            draweeView.setTag(uri);
            draweeView.setController(controller);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am part of the Fresco team and may be able to help.
It is strange that you experience the same issue with low-res/high-res combination. If the image is currently displayed, it means it should be in the bitmap memory cache, which in turn means that it should be able to load immediately when set as a low-res image the next time you are switching to the next frame.
Are you sure that you are setting the correct uri as low-res image? `(Uri) draweeView.getTag()` looks kind of suspicious. I would double check that part.

If the uri is indeed correct, but the image is not in the bitmap cache anymore, it would be worth investigating why the image that is visible is not cached anymore, as we have explicit logic in place that should prevent evicting visible images. See how to track this with verbose logging [here](http://frescolib.org/docs/troubleshooting.html#_).

If all of the above fails, third options is to actually implement your own [DataSource](http://frescolib.org/docs/datasources-datasubscribers.html#_). I can help with that, but this might be somewhat involving. The basic idea is to implement a `DataSource` that wraps another `DataSource` that actually provides the image. Then you could do something like this:

```
// keep this instance somewhere
mMyDataSourceSupplier = new MyDataSourceSupplier();

// build controller by specifying your custom datasource supplier instead of specifying any URIs.
Fresco.newDraweeControllerBuilder()
  .setDataSourceSupplier(mMyDataSourceSupplier)
  .build()

// later, when you need to change the image do
mMyDataSourceSupplier.setUri(nextUri);

// this is just an outline
class MyDataSourceSupplier implements Supplier<DataSource<CloseableReference<CloseableImage>>> {

  private Uri mCurrentUri;
  private DataSource<CloseableReference<CloseableImage>> mCurrentDataSource;

  public void setUri(Uri uri) {
    mCurrentUri = uri;
    if (mCurrentDatasource != null) {
      mCurrentDataSource.setUri(uri);
    }
  }

  @Override
  public DataSource<CloseableReference<CloseableImage>> get() {
    mCurrentDataSource = new MyDataSource();
    mCurrentDataSource.setUri(uri);
    return mCurrentDataSource;
  }

  private class MyDataSource extends AbstractDataSource<CloseableReference<CloseableImage>> {
    private DataSource mUnderlyingDataSource;

    @Override
    protected void closeResult(@Nullable CloseableReference<CloseableImage> result) {
      CloseableReference.closeSafely(result);
    }

    @Override
    @Nullable
    public CloseableReference<CloseableImage> getResult() {
      return CloseableReference.cloneOrNull(super.getResult());
    }


    @Override
    public boolean close() {
      if (mUnderlyingDataSource != null) {
        mUnderlyingDataSource.close();
        mUnderlyingDataSource = null;
      }
      return super.close();
    }

    public void setUri(Uri uri) {
      if (mUnderlyingDataSource != null) {
        mUnderlyingDataSource.close();
        mUnderlyingDataSource = null;
      }
      if (uri != null && !isClosed()) {
        mUnderlyingDataSource = Fresco.getImagePipeline().fetchDecodedImage(ImageRequest.fromUri(uri), null);
        mUnderlyingDataSource.subscribe(new BaseDataSubscriber {
          @Override
          protected void onNewResultImpl(DataSource<List<CloseableReference<CloseableImage>>> dataSource) {
            MyDataSource.super.setResult(dataSource.getResult(), false);
          }
        });
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for this. I'm going to give this a try next week and will let you know about the results.

Comment: @plamenko why did you decide to hide existing image when loading of new one started? providing the choice hide it or not appears to be much more useful..

Comment: @AntonMalyshev, it's not that we decided to hide the existing image per se. This is rather a consequence of the Drawee design. Drawee obtains images to display from a DataSource (which in turn comes from a Supplier<DataSource>). Drawee only has a single supplier which greatly simplifies design as the muxing logic is encapsulated there instead of in Drawee controller. A clean way to achieve this functionality with Drawee is to have a supplier that does that.

Comment: @AntonMalyshev, ...so your question should rather be formulated like "Why doesn't Fresco provide such a supplier out of the box?". The answer is simply there was not need for it at the time. We welcome pull requests and if the provided supplier is generic enough and commonly requested, we will be happy to ship it with Fresco.